# pdflatex error when rendering TeX as PDF in TeXstudio on Windows 7

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texstudio

I installed TeX using MiKTeX and installed TeXstudio using the basic installer, but whenever I compile a TeX file (.tex) using pdflatex in TeXstudio I receive this error:
[image]

TeXworks (which came bundled with MiKTeX) is able to compile using pdflatex without a problem.

I tried the command line to see what was going on and this is what I got:

```
C:\Users\Brenton\Documents\LaTeX>pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Amide condensation reaction".tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

I have also tried to configure the program, changing pdflatex.exe in the command for pdftex to the full location of pdflatex on my system. These are my settings.

[image]

but still I receive this message:

```
Process started: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Amide condensation reaction".tex

Process exited with error(s)
```

Comment: since you can compile using texwork there is no problem with miktex. may be you need to give miktex path manully in texstudio, go to obtions->configure texstudio->commands

Comment: Sorry, I already tried that I should have mentioned it. I'll add it to my question.

Comment: "Fatal Format" indicates that you should recreate the formats in miktex settings (depending on the location of the current format, either admin or user version). But if the format is wrong it shouldn't work in texworks either. Btw: Avoid absolute pathes in the configuration. There are not needed for the miktex applications and can only confuse.

Answer (score 1):

The error message "Fatal format file error; I'm stymied" means that TeX binary is trying to load `latex.fmt` (or `pdflatex.fmt`) but the version of this TeX binary differs from another TeX binary which created such `latex.fmt`. There could be two reasons: you have installed two TeX binaries (in different versions) or you have somewhere in your computer the old `latex.fmt` from previous TeX installation.

The `pdflatex.exe` must be implemented as one what runs TeX binary (most probably `pdftex.exe`) and sets the message to this binary: "hey, load `pdflatex.fmt`". And this loading is broken as described above. I don't know how exactly it is implemented in MikTeX, sorry. I never used MS Windows.

New TeX distributions has more TeX binaries: "tex", "pdftex", "luatex" and "xetex". If one of them creates `file.fmt` and another of them reads such `file.fmt` then the error message mentioned above occurs too. This is reason why TeX distributions save the generated `file.fmt` to directories specific for used TeX binary and they have implemented a searching system over such directory trees.